# VBS MsgBox Needs response before anything else

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

I want to make a **Message box** in VBS that makes the user unable to run any other application on the desktop/click on anything.

Like the **dialog boxes** windows will make that makes a little negative sound when you try to click out of the box. I've tried the SystemModula setting (4096) but that doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions? Heres what i got.

```
msgbox "test",4+4096+48,"test"
```

If you have any other suggestions like running through a cmd to activate this feature then i'm okay with that aswell.

Comment: @GSerg I've seen this, but The application only remains on top of all other applications, but it still allows the activation of applications. I read it had something to do with modern Win32 systems doing this, but i also wanted to know if there was a way to reenable the old Win16 way of doing it, where no application can be runned.

Comment: Making a dialog system-modal is the only option you have in VBScript. With that said: I don't recommend ever using this feature. Do not nag your users.

Comment: Its for a small login system for 10 computers. Its not for nagging them. Then I'll but a shortcut to the vbe in start so it starts from it.